# Xcode: Linker Command failed with exit code for unity game

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build `xcode` for my `unity` game, the following error occurring:

> "Linker command failed with xcode 1 (use -ve to see invocation)"

`Bitcode` enable is YES and I have clean my project but error is there.

Comment: Double-click on the error to see the actual linker message, then copy-paste it in your question. Also, for what type of build are you getting the error (simulator, actual device – and if so, which, upload build...)?

Comment: also, try setting bitcode to no

Comment: Which third party SDK is in your project?